"ulimit -c unlimited" fails when done "sudo user -c shell-some-script"
I have on a Linux server with SuSE Linux Enterprise 15 SP5 the following situation:
I have two unpriv users "sisis" and "jenkins" which are both allowed (based on entries in /etc/security/limits.conf) to run the shell build-in command "ulimit -c unlimited":
linux:~ # su - jenkins

jenkins@linux:~> id
uid=1003(jenkins) gid=100(users) Gruppen=100(users)
jenkins@linux:~> ulimit -c unlimited ; echo $?
0
exit

linux:~ # su - sisis
sisis@linux:~> id
uid=900118(sisis) gid=900118(sisis) Gruppen=900118(sisis),403(userdevl)
sisis@linux:~> ulimit -c unlimited ; echo $?
0
exit

But, when the user "jenkins" wants to do this in a shell script as user "sisis", this gives an error:
linux:~ # su - jenkins
jenkins@linux:~> cat /tmp/ulimit.sh
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=C
ulimit -c unlimited
jenkins@linux:~> sudo -u sisis -g sisis /tmp/ulimit.sh
/tmp/ulimit.sh: line 3: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

The background of this silly question is, that for test automation from another server (a Jenkins Continuous Integration server) jobs are started remotely as
ssh jenkins@linux bash CATserver_start.sh
+ sudo -u sisis /opt/lib/sisis/catserver/etc/S99catserver.testdb start

i.e. the "ulimit -c unlimited" command is issued in the above shellscript /opt/lib/sisis/catserver/etc/S99catserver.testdb which in production is started as user "sisis", but in test automation from the Jenkins CI server via SSH as user "jenkins".
Any ideas?

The difference here is when using su - jenkins your are substituing the user identity to jenkins but you keep the privileges of the Super User to perform the ulimit -c unlimited operation.
Whereas when using sudo -u jenkins ... you are instead running the following command with the privileges of the jenkins user.
Watch the difference:
su switches user identity while preserving original user's privileges:
su jenkins sh -c 'ulimit -c unlimited; echo $?'


0

sudo -u runs command on behalf of user with user's privileges:
sudo -u jenkins sh -c 'ulimit -c unlimited; echo $?'


sh: 1: jenkins: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
2



Not clear. A sudo -u jenkins sh -c 'ulimit -c unlimited; echo $?' runs (as you say) the command with the user's (jenkins) privs. And this user has the priv to set 'unlimited':
$ ssh jenkins@linux
Last login: Thu Feb 29 08:06:06 2024 from 10.25.75.53
jenkins@linux:~> ulimit -c unlimited
jenkins@linux:~> echo $?
0

I think you may get a better answer with posting this to superuser instead.

The solution was given in
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/781835/ulimit-c-unlimited-fails-when-done-sudo-user-c-shell-some-script
which points to a known problem, see here:
https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020902
